# Masking vector A for elements that does not match vector B

Tags: arrays, math, vector, filter, mask

If I have a vector v = {10,9,8}, and a vector y = {10,5,7}. How can I write this so that it results in a vector x = {1,0,0}. In other Words, set ones where elements match, and zeroes if not? How would one write this in a mathematical way, or by using functional language terms like filter, map or such.

Comment: Well that depends, what sort of language would you like to do it in? Or is it a pure math question?

Comment: @harold yes, sorry for not making that clear enough. Just theoretically and mathematically.

Answer (score 1):

Although the question might be considered off-topic, the [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) comes to mind. If `n` is a nonnegative integer, and `v,y in R^n`, one can define the desired vector as `x:={x_1,...,x_n}` where `x_i = delta_v_i,y_i` for each `i in {1,...n}`.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I do not have enough knowledge to understand what you are suggesting right away so I am not the right person to accept it as the correct answer. What do you think about using some kind of logic-rooted math description of the problem? I don't understand if what I ask is possible to understand. Please let me know otherwise.